# How can I produce a SKI from RSA public Key in node js?

Tags: javascript, rsa, x509, identifier

I am trying to modify `fabric-sdk-node` project to use it with RSA certs and keys.

And for now I have no idea on how to produce a SKI (X509v3 Subject Key Identifier) with a RSA public key.

That project is using `jsrsasign` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsrsasign) on the crypto things.

I have found in the `jsrsasign` issue page on Github.com which can [produce SKI with ECDSA](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/issues/402), but still no clue in the RSA ones.

Any advice will be welcomed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have almost test every method in package `jsrsasign`, but still not found anything useful.

So I look outside the box and think, the X509V3 Subject Key Identifier(SKI) was produced by the default `sha1` hash algo. However, what we have done in the hyperledger/fabric, defined that the hash algo to be `sha256`. So what if the `jsrsasign` has made that hash algo hardcoded with `sha1`? (This is a guess, please correct me if I am wrong.)

With that thought, I have tried on another package `node-forge`, which just solved my problem.

Here is the demo:

```js
const nodeForge = require("node-forge");
const pki = nodeForge.pki;

const jsrsa = require("jsrsasign");
const KEYUTIL = jsrsa.KEYUTIL;


const rsaPubKeyPem = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID<.........>Y/gRUg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
`;

const pubKey = KEYUTIL.getKey(rsaPubKeyPem);
const publicKey = pki.rsa.setPublicKey(pubKey.n,pubKey.e);

console.log(pki.getPublicKeyFingerprint(publicKey,{
    md: nodeForge.sha256.create(),
    encoding: 'hex',
    delimiter: ':'}));
```

And we have got the exactly same SKI as the openssl did.
This will import another crypto package, and it looked ugly.
Please advise if you have any good ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: "Thank you. I've add SubjectKeyIdentifier extension support in 8.0.14 release today." 
The `jsrsasign` package has add new function to produce SKI, no need to import `node-forge` again. Thanks for the effort!